# Can a feature class be stored as a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, shapefile, feature-class

This is a general question about how a feature class is stored or can be stored using python/arcpy.

Can a list of created points (a feature class) be saved as a shapefile or in a shapefile, or to create a new feature class do you have to create a gdb and then add the feature class to it, then ultimately convert this to a shapefile using ArcPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a shapefile is considered a Feature Class, which lends it several attributes.

Esri provides this overview about the shapefile <updated link 200828 based on comment by @Rex below>[Geoprocessing considerations for shapefile output](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm)
:

> A shapefile is an Esri vector data storage format for storing the
> location, shape, and attributes of geographic features. It is stored
> as a set of related files and contains one feature class. Shapefiles
> often contain large features with a lot of associated data and
> historically have been used in GIS desktop applications such as ArcGIS
> for Desktop and ArcGIS Explorer Desktop. If you have a small amount of
> data in a shapefile—generally fewer than 1,000 features—you can make
> it available for others to view through a web browser by adding it as
> a .zip file containing the .shp, .shx, .dbf, and .prj files to a map
> you create with the map viewer.
>
> When you add a shapefile, the map viewer converts it to a format that
> web clients can quickly read and display. To help further improve the
> performance of the display, you can choose to generalize the features
> in your shapefile. Generalizing reduces the size of the shapefile by
> simplifying the features and is often appropriate for data at small
> scales.

To expand further, the Duke University Libraries provides additional insight to both the shapefile and feature classes, providing a good comparison.

Here is a snippet from the [article](http://blogs.library.duke.edu/data/2015/09/14/shapefiles-vs-geodatabases/):

Feature datasets store Feature Classes (which are the equivalent to shapefiles) with the same coordinate system.  Like shapefiles, users can create points, lines, and polygons with feature classes; feature classes also have the ability to create annotation, and dimension features.

[image]

Comment: Note that a feature dataset should only be used to group features _which are related spatially_ and not just as a way to organise a geodatabase "neatly". "Their primary purpose is for organizing related feature classes into a common dataset for building a topology, a network dataset, a terrain dataset, or a geometric network" [reference](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_working_with_feature_datasets)

Comment: For the purposes of the question and by many general definitions, a shapefile is equivalent to a feature class, but a feature class an esri geodatabase can have many different properties.  The link about shapefiles above is regarding AGOL and is a very narrow one.  I would encourage anyone pondering this question to view this [link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm) from esri.

Answer (score 7):

To put it really simply, a shapefile is a feature class that is not stored within a geodatabase. So you can use a tool like `Conversion > Feature Class To Feature Class` (or `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion`) and convert a feature class or layer to a shapefile.

Modifying the sample script from [Feature Class to Feature Class Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) slightly, here is an example of converting a feature class to a shapefile.  This takes a feature class called `buildings_point` from a geodatabase `C:\data\GreenvalleyDB.mdb\PublicBuildings`and outputs them to a shapefile `postoffices.shp` in the folder `C:\output`

```py
# Name: FeatureClassToFeatureClass_Example2.py
# Description: Use FeatureClassToFeatureClass with an expression to create a subset
# of the original feature class.  

# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/GreenvalleyDB.mdb/PublicBuildings"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = "buildings_point"
outLocation = "C:/output"
outFeatureClass = "postoffices.shp"
expression = ""

# Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a [Spatial Times blog entitled Shapefile vs Feature Class](http://www.spatialtimes.com/2014/06/shapefile-vs-feature-class/) by [searching Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=shapefile%20feature%20class%20comparison):

> A Shapefile is a Feature Class. Although the intended question
>   probably wasn’t answered here. But let’s go a little deeper into this
>   before moving on, so what is a Feature Class then (from:
>   http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Feature_class)?
>
> Feature classes are homogeneous collections of common features, each
>   having the same spatial representation, such as points, lines, or
>   polygons, and a common set of attribute columns, for example, a line
>   feature class for representing road centerlines.
>
> By this definition, a Shapefile is a Feature Class.